# Location of pk value in DRF @detail_view

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using the default Django Rest Framework (DRF) Viewsets, the Detail URLs end with the `pk` value at the end of the URL e.g. `/user/1`. My confusion though is that if you create a custom end-point and use the [`@detail_route`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator, the URL ends up like `/user/1/change_password`. Why the difference in the placement of the `pk` value?

Comment: you can take a look at there documentation regarding router http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routers

Comment: I see where its stated that that is the way it is: `{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}`. It isn't stated why it is that way which is what I was after but I will check out the docs. Thanks.